# Is not a valid service exception in JAX-WS

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I am taking reference from http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

This is my  **HelloWorldClient** class

```
package WebService;


import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;



public class HelloWorldClient{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8099/dummy1/dummy2?wsdl");

        //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
    //2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
        QName qname = new QName("http://localhost:8099/dummy1/dummy2?wsdl", "HelloWorldImplService");


        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);

        System.out.println(hello.getHelloWorldAsString("mkyong"));

    }

}
```

When running this class i am getting error from  below line of code

```
Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {http://localhost:8099/dummy1/dummy2?wsdl}HelloWorldImplService is not a valid service. Valid services are: {http://WebService/}HelloWorldImplService
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:680)
    at WebService.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:19)
```

In the reference example in HelloWorldClient class it has

```
    QName qname = new QName("http://ws.mkyong.com/", "HelloWorldImplService");
```

In my case i have replaced it with

```
    QName qname = new QName("http://localhost:8099/dummy1/dummy2?wsdl", "HelloWorldImplService");
```

I could not figure out where i have made mistake .When i run 
`http://localhost:8099/dummy1/dummy2?wsdl` it is working fine.But ,when i access from client i am getting above mentioned exception.Any help please ?

Answer (score 6):

Try to replace

```
QName qname = new QName("http://localhost:8099/dummy1/dummy2?wsdl", "HelloWorldImplService");
```

with

```
QName qname = new QName("http://WebService/", "HelloWorldImplService");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my recipe to solve this issue:

1. run the publisher class written by Mkyong;

2. open the url (ex: http://localhost:8099/dummy1/dummy2?wsdl) in browser;

3. check if "targetNamespace" property in WSDL equals to the 1st argument in QName constructor. If it doesn't, set it from WSDL;

4.  check if "name" property in WSDL equals to the 2nd argument in QName constructor. If it doesn't, set it from WSDL;

5. stop both the client and the publisher;

6. run the publisher;

7. run the client;

8. enjoy the result =)

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what to fix :

Valid services are: `{http://WebService/}HelloWorldImplService`

for me the following was necessary:

```
QName qname = new QName("http://WebService/" , "HelloWorldImplService");
```

Comment: Thanks! I compleatly missed this very useful information in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I do believe that first argument in QName instantiation should be without that *?wsdl*. You are asked for providing namespace, not the URI of WSDL document.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I created WebServiceClient and WebServices projects.
    And same files:
    WebServiceClient ::
    webservices.HelloWorld.java
    webservices.HelloWorldClient.java

```
WebServices :: 
webservices.HelloWorld.java
webservices.HelloWorldImpl.java
webservices.HelloWorldPublisher.java

I used NetBeans 8. In both project must have same name of package and 

QName qname = new QName("http://webservices/", "HelloWorldImplService");
in webservices.HelloWorldClient.java.
The end. It runs ! Sorry My english. (Bobojonov Farruh)
```