# "javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: is not a valid service." proxy issue?

Tags: java, web-services, https, proxy, wsimport

As a premise, I am not very experienced yet, but I have tried to read and search everything I possibly could, related to this topic, and still no luck.

I was given a simple client to call a webservice but once it was fully setup (which included the use of a certificate and a couple more properties to set) I got the error mentioned in the title:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {http://http://cert.controller.portaapplicativa.ictechnology.it//}MyService is not a valid service. Valid services are: 
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:187)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at package.client.wsimport.MyService..<init>(MyService.java:46)
    at package.client.Client.doRicercaDEN(Client.java:55)
    at package.client.Client.main(Client.java:36)
```

I tried generating the client again with JAX-WS:

```
java -classpath C:\Programmi\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\lib\tools.jar com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport -verbose C:\WsdlFile.wsdl -p package.client.wsimport -s C:\tmp\ws\
```

And I get the same issue. I am using a local copy of the wsdl because wsimport doesn't seem to like the certificate I'm trying to set in the properties (I'm most likely doing something wrong, but I opted for the simple workaround, given I have more pressing issues).

Trying to use SoapUI to test the service, everything works fine, though I need to set the preferences for the proxy to "None".

So I tried to make sure the connection doesn't use any proxy in my client as well:

```
(...)
systemSettings.remove("http.proxyHost");
systemSettings.remove("http.proxyPort");
systemSettings.remove("https.proxyHost");
systemSettings.remove("https.proxyPort");
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts","*");
System.setProperty("https.nonProxyHosts","*");
```

(BTW, before "*", which as I understand it should work as a wildcard for "every domain", I have tried specifying the specific domains as well)
Anyway, the result is always the same.

Is there something I am doing wrong, something left to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, what I was missing was importing the certificate in my local truststore (or better, when I first tried doing so, I thought I was using the correct truststore, but I wasn't).

For anyone who may need it, here is an explanation of how to do that using keytool: http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html

Another option is to use specific GUI like Portecle.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is a proxy issue. If you can share the code you are using to create the Service object it might help. 
As a kick start try reading the below thread 
[Is not a valid service exception in JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533904/is-not-a-valid-service-exception-in-jax-ws)

What I think is that the QName you have provided when creating the Service is not proper. To get the correct QName you might try to open the generated stub.

Comment: I edited the question to show how I created the client.

As for the QName:  

`public MyService() {
 super(MYSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://namespace.it/", "MyService"));
}`  
 
MYSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION is the actual wsdl URL,

MyService comes from   
`<service name="MyService">`  

http://namespace.it/ is from   
`<definitions [...] targetNamespace="http://cert.controller.portaApplicativa.ictechnology.it/">`  

and   
`<xsd:schema>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://cert.controller.portaApplicativa.ictechnology.it/" schemaLocation="PortaApplicativaXsd.xsd"></xsd:import>
</xsd:schema>`

Comment: try using http://cert.controller.portaApplicativa.ictechnology.it/ instead of http://namespace.it/.

Comment: Uh, I actually am, I was going to change all actual namespaces, service name, and such since I'm not aware of what I can or cannot make public, and I missed that one. At this point, let me just change it in my question, sorry about the confusion. (Forgot I can't edit the comment, instead)

Comment: I tried to verify that there is nothing I messed up in the rest of the client, and using http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL as an example I changed my MYSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION, the namespace and service name (plus set the proxy properties), and it worked as expected (to then stop working at the next instruction, again as expected, since I kept the rest of the code, and it tries to get a port that doesn't exist on the new ws).  
  
At this point, if it's not the proxy and the namespace is correct, the only guess I have left is that I'm not reading the wsdl correctly.

Comment: As it turns out, what I was missing was importing the certificate in my local truststore (or better, when I first tried doing so, I thought I was using the correct truststore, but I wasn't).

For anyone who may need it, here is an explanation of how to do that using keytool: http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html

Another option is to use specific GUI like Portecle.